# Blindly preventing Javascript global var collision

Tags: javascript

Is it a good idea to blindly wrap every .js file with something like the following, to avoid the possibility of global var collision?

```
 (function(){ /*Javascript file contents here*/ })();
```

IF the idea is correct, is there better code to use for that?

And is there a problem if a file already contains that, i.e. double-nesting?

Comment: Structuring your code as such doesn't prevent it from polluting the window namespace.

Comment: it won't prevent it, but it might help.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it's probably not a bad idea, but I would combine it with `"use strict"` to also ensure that variables used without `var` are caught too.

Double-nesting won't actually break anything, but do be aware that there might be a (hopefully very) small performance hit when resolving global variables because there'd now be two scopes to climb out of instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see this is that JavaScript has function-based scoping rules.

What we have here is an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) which is a feature of the JavaScript language enabling a function to be declared and invoked in one convenient expression.

```
(function(){ /*Javascript file contents here*/ })();
```

Any `var` or `function` declarations inside this IIFE will not be visible outside of the the IIFE unless explicitly revealed (for example, but returning them on an object).

```
(function(){ 
  function notRevealed() {}
  function revealed() {}
  myApp.revealed = revealed;
})(myApp);

notRevealed; //undefined
revealed; //undefined
myApp.revealed //defined
```

In order to catch another common class of errors you'll want to add `'use strict';` to the top of your function to ensure that variables defined without `var` are not placed on the global object as properties and that `this` is not erroneously set to the global object.

```
(function(){ 'use strict'; /*Javascript file contents here*/ })();
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

- It won't stop scripts making globals by omitting `var`.
- It won't stop scripts making globals by explicitly setting them as properties of the `window` object
- It may break scripts that depend on globals (via, for example, passing strings to `setTimeout` or generating `onclick` attributes from strings).

Comment: IMHO, a script that depends on strings for `setTimeout` or for inline (DOM0) handlers is already broken ;-)